# H2 database update table execution takes too long when MVCC=true

Tags: h2

I have a table with 18 columns with a primary key and 8 indexes. If I make a usual connection to H2 DB (embedded mode) and update the non-index field of this table, it takes around 20 seconds in H2 console to update 50000 records. However, if I set MVCC=true in connection string and then try to update SAME 50000 records, the table does not get updated for even more than 30 minutes

Schema below

```
CREATE TABLE
    TEMP
    (
        SWITCHIPADDRESS VARCHAR(16),
        ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        MACADDRESS VARCHAR(14),
        USERID VARCHAR(32),
        TIMESTMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        LINKCOUNT INTEGER,
        HASLINKTOSWITCH BOOLEAN,
        LINKIPADDR VARCHAR(16),
        IFINDEX INTEGER,
        PORT INTEGER,
        SLOT INTEGER,
        VLANID INTEGER,
        IFSPEED INTEGER,
        IFADMINSTATUS INTEGER,
        PORTDUPLEXMODE INTEGER,
        UNP VARCHAR(32),
        DOMAIN INTEGER,
        DISPOSITION INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )
```

Indexes

```
KEY `ForwardIdx` (`SwitchIPAddress`,`MACAddress`,`slot`,`port`),
KEY `ForwardSwIPIdx` (`SwitchIPAddress`),
KEY `ForwardMACIdx` (`MACAddress`),
KEY `ForwardSlotIdx` (`slot`),
KEY `ForwardPortIdx` (`port`),
KEY `ForwardVlanIdx` (`VlanID`),
KEY `UserIdIdx` (`UserId`),
KEY `UNPIdx` (`UNP`)
```

I can see in the trace log file that thousands of keys are first getting removed and then getting added which is probably taking time. But I wonder, why would key realignment required when what is being done is a simple update on non-idx field.

The problem remains even if I have just 1 index which is used in where clause.

Can someone please let me know how to speed this up and improve update performance out here. Is deletion and then addition of leys by design>>

Our application is multi-threaded and we are getting "Timeout error trying to lock table" issues for which I have added MVCC=true in the connection line and now ran into another problem.

Comment: Could you try to create a simple, reproducible test case (a SQL script would be best).

Answer (score 0):

MVCC mode is experimental. Also, we going to replace it as some point with a different engine, so using it really a "at your own risk" solution.

I suggest that you turn MVCC mode off, and try to fix your timeout problem some other way.